# schema / structured data

Tags: schema.org, microdata, structured-data

I am trying to figure out the best way to use schema / structured data on two types of pages.  One is an image gallery and one is a video page.

Here is data that is present on each type of page:

1. Title of gallery
2. Description of gallery
3. Name, picture and profile link of the person who submitted the gallery
4. Review Text
5. Name, picture and profile link of the reviewer
6. Date gallery was posted
7. Average rating of the gallery
8. Individual images in the gallery
9. Individual comments left by viewers of the gallery

Video page have almost the same information minus:

Individual images in the gallery

Instead, it has the video, video thumbnail and video duration

I'm a novice at using structured data and I'm hoping if I can get to grips with a single type of schema, I'll be able to apply it to other areas of my site like forums, blogs, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: _"hoping if I can get to grips with a single type of schema"_ https://schema.org/WebPage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex question because it involves using multiple types of structured data definitions. Either microdata or rdf are recommended by google. Start with the basics and add in other elements once you have them working. Google's testing tool and the [Structured data linter](http://linter.structured-data.org) will check them for you.

This [generator](http://www.microdatagenerator.com/image-object-schema/) will help, just remove the photographed by part.

The https://schema.org/ImageGallery schema exists, which will contain one or more images (images use http://schema.org/ImageObjects). Example from [photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/seo.html) with the images each including a link to a larger image:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl">
        <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>

    <!-- optionally use this method to store image dimensions for PhotoSwipe -->
    <meta itemprop="width" content="300">
    <meta itemprop="height" content="600">

    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">
        Long image description

        <!-- optionally define copyright -->
        <span itemprop="copyrightHolder">Photo: AP</span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl">
        <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Long image description</figcaption>
 </figure>

 ...

</div>
```

Each of the following things are **properties** of **ImageObject**, so put these in where they are in your code, e.g. for **Title of gallery** use the property `headline` as follows:

```
<span itemprop="headline">My trip to Paris</span>
```

Properties of ImageGallery you can use:

- **about** A description of gallery
- **aggregateRating** average rating, eg "3.5"
- **dateCreated** Date gallery was posted
- **comment** use either another Thing for each (which would let you give the person's name and other details separately - using http://schema.org/Comment) or fill out one `comment` line per comment.  Individual comments left by viewers of the gallery

Complex ones using more Things (more structured data) -

- **author** with Name, picture and profile link -  either just add a link to their own page or social media profile, or use the http://schema.org/Person schema (name, url and image properties) as below

`<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">`

`<span itemprop="name">Joe bloggs</span>`

`&nbsp;<img src="joebloggs.png"  itemprop="image" />&nbsp`

`<a itemprop="url" href="http://yourwebsite.com/joeblogs.html">View Profile</a>`

`</span>`

**Review** TextName, picture and profile link of the reviewer

This can be done like the author one above, but using the http://schema.org/Review schema

Comment: What ultimately confuses me is declaring the "Thing".  I was using an example from another site (can't remember the URL) and started using something like this:
`<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">`
Do I then need to declare other things in divs like /Person and /ImageGallery
This is primarily where I'm stumbling.

Comment: the structured data stuff just slots into the `<div>`s and links that you already have. The example above, says the whole `<body>` is a WebPage, the `<body>` tag was already there. So find either a `<body>` or `<div>` that includes as much of your page as possible, then add **itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"** inside it. Then check it against the google structured data tool, then add another line or two by adding to another `<div>` then test again. If you want to put several bits of data on the same line you just create a new `<span>` tag (it won't format anything).Takes time

Comment: just edited my answer to give a link to a generator for generating an ImageObject. Fill out the form and it will do the basics for you.